# How to dynamically create a checkbox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

We are dynamically creating multiples `checkbox` in JavaScript.
But, there is one problem.
The checkbox has been created, but it's label is not visible.
We confirmed that it was created properly by the developer tool.
But I can't see the label  on the web.
How do we deal with this?
I attach the photo.
I also attach the code.

```
radio.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
radio.setAttribute("id", "lo_radio");
radio.setAttribute("name", "choose");
radio2.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
radio2.setAttribute("id", "lo_radio2");
radio2.setAttribute("name", "choose");
... 
 if(j==1){
        var color = document.getElementById("#color_li");
        //ul.insertBefore(radio, color);
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        ul.insertBefore(label, color);
        label.appendChild(radio);
        radio.innerHTML = radio.innerHTML + "10자";
        label.appendChild(radio);
    
//      ul.insertBefore(radio2, color);
        ul.insertBefore(label, color);
        label.appendChild(radio2);
        radio2.innerHTML = radio2.innerHTML + "30자";
        ul.insertBefore(lo_select, color);


        $("#lo_li").click(function() {  
            if($("#lo_select").is(":visible")){
                  $("#lo_select").slideUp();
            }
            else{   
                $("#lo_select").slideDown();
            }});

    }
...
//HTML
<section id = "section1_r" style = "background-color : #525252; font-family : a타이틀고딕1, sans_serif">
<div id = "a2">
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwoHx.png)

HTML in browser console:

[image]

** 위치 = "location" (in Korean)

Comment: checkbox don't have innerHTML, you need to append the text inside the label beside the checkbox.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. On a first glimpse, I see some irregularities in your HTML: An UL element must contain only LI elements; A LABEL element should enclose at most one INPUT; both of your INPUTs share the same name (valid just in radiobuttons). Please, provide us your complete javascript function, and also the complete generated HTML.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to create a checkbox programmatically:

```js
const label = document.createElement("label");
const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
checkbox.type="checkbox";
checkbox.id="some-id";
checkbox.name="some-name";
const textContent = document.createTextNode("Label text content");

label.appendChild(checkbox);
label.appendChild(textContent);

document.body.appendChild(label);
```